# ReduceRegions not writting to feature properties in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, features, feature-collection, reducers

I am trying to apply `reduceRegions()` to extract average precipitation from the [TerraClimate dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/IDAHO_EPSCOR_TERRACLIMATE) within each polygon of a feature collection. The problem is that the output of the reduction is *not* written to each feature property as expected. It only appears in the columns of the output feature collection. The code below is a simple implementation on the first image of the collection, using an arbitrary feature collection with 3 polygons. My end goal is to map the `reduceRegions()` function to the whole TerraClimate collection. For this, I followed the steps to use `reduceRegions()`outlined in this previous post: [Calculate mean EVI for multiple polygons across an image collection in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343696/calculate-mean-evi-for-multiple-polygons-across-an-image-collection-in-google-ea)

The problem, and my question, is why is the result of `reduceRegions()`not writing / added to the feature properties as expected? It does so in the example given in the post above (mean EVI index example). As a result, I cannot map the `reduceRegions()`function to the whole collection.

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/49680c8f2c6d505ddf437a59b015e906

Coming back to my post after some more works, it seems that this is caused by having null values returned by `reduceRegions()`, so that the property is not set in this case. Now, the only way to NOT have null values is to use scale: 30 with the `reduceRegions()`. The *TerraClimate* data is in geographic projections with a 2.5 arcminute resolution (about 4 km). Whenever I use a different scale value (1, 20, 40, 100.. 1000), I only get null values. It only works with 30 meters for scale. Anyone knows what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Someone else asked a similar question on the earth-engine list, and it seems indeed this is a bug! A quick workaround was found by Gennadii ([ee list link](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/google-earth-engine-developers/CAHC%3D2eLu%3Dt-WnNQ8zLw%3Dw9Fih1U-x2Za%2Bx2stuW5WLfKT%3DnYZQ%40mail.gmail.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer), [code link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0467ee5f910f9958eceb270520e2b57a)), suggesting to add a dummy operation like `.add(0)` which apparently will resolve the underlying caching issue.

Your code would be:

```
var table = /* color: #d63000 */ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-90.91436262497096, 53.98605219620492],
                  [-86.5198, 49.4155],[-77.5549, 52.4602]]]),
            {"system:index": "0"}),
        ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Polygon(
                [[[-67.7991, 53.674],[-65.0745, 50.935],[-59.8010, 53.308]]]),
            {"system:index": "1"}),
        ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Polygon(
                [[[-110.9534, 50.99],[-107.6135, 49.75],[-104.7131, 52.46]]]),
            {"system:index": "2"})]);

Map.centerObject(table,4);
Map.addLayer(table)
print ('table',table);

// TERRACLIM COLLECTION
var startYr = 2018;
var endYr = 2018; 
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startYr,01,01);
//var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endYr+1,01,01); //**NOTE: the end date in .filterDate() is exclusive, so this allows all days in 2019 to be included
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endYr,03,01); //**NOTE: the end date in .filterDate() is exclusive, so this allows all days in 2019 to be included

var precipCollection = ee.ImageCollection("IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE").select('pr').filterDate(startDate, endDate);
Map.addLayer(precipCollection.first())
print('precipCollection',precipCollection)

// ---Function to extract spatial averages of monthly TerraClim variables within basins---
var precipproj = ee.Image(precipCollection.first()).projection();


print('precipproj',precipproj)
var im1 = precipCollection.first().toDouble().add(0);
print('im1',im1)


var im1_reduced = im1.reduceRegions({
    collection: table,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    crs: precipproj
  });
print('im1 reduced',im1_reduced)
```